# N1QL select number-only key

Tags: couchbase, sql++

i have a document like

```
{
    "bucket_name": {
      "0": 2,
      "1": 107,
      "2": 61,
      "3": 428,
      "username": "tester2",
      "obj_type": 21,
      "date": 1562416800
    }
}
```

how i can do select to number-only json key like that, i tried something like :

```
select 0 from bucket_name where obj_type=21 and username='tester'
```

but it's return :

```
[
    {
      "$1": 0,
    },
    {
      "$1": 0,
    },
    {
      "$1": 0,
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

USE back-ticks (i.e. escaped-identifiers) https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/identifiers.html

```
SELECT `0` 
FROM bucket_name
WHERE obj_type=21 AND username='tester';
```